# Convert string to date without considering timezone

Tags: javascript, date

From service I get date string in format `'yyyy-mm-dd'` (eb, '2017-09-14')

In JavaScript, I convert this string to Date like as mentioned below:

```
new Date('2017-09-14')
```

It works just fine. But I am facing problem in different time zones. For example

> **In EST Timezone**: Wed Sep 13 2017 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) and
>
> **In IST Timezone**: Thu Sep 14 2017 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Is there a way to convert it to the same date e.g. `Sep 14, 2017`

Comment: So the aim is to convert to the GMT time zone, is that correct?

Comment: Maybe `(new Date('2017-09-14')).toUTCString()`

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/date-utc-javascript/

Comment: the two *are the same date* though :/

Comment: You might want to use `new Date('2017-09-14').getTimezoneOffset()`

Comment: @storaged: when i call `new Date('2017-09-14')` it should give me 14 Sept regardless of timezone.

Comment: I always pass date as UTC value, when I show it to end users, I will convert it to local time.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can do it like this

```
var d=new Date(date value);
var actualDate=d.getDate();
var actualMonth=d.getMonth()+1;
var actualYear=d.getFullYear();    
var formattedDate=actualDate + '/' + actualMonth + '/' + actualYear;
```

You can save it to any format